# Finding sequences of characters, whichever's first

Tags: java, string

I wrote a code that finds four different sequences of characters.

ATG is always at the start and TAG, TGA or TAA are the "stop" sequences.

The number of characters in between START and STOP sequences should by a multiple of 3.

For example in the following String: ACC**ATG**CCC**TAG**TTT my program returns **ATG**CCC**TAG**.

And in this string: AA**ATG**CC**TAG**T**TAA** the program returns **ATG**CCTAGT**TAA**, because the number of characters between ATG and TGA is not a multiple of three, so it looks for the next "stop" sequence, which is TAA in this case.

Here's the code:

```
public class TagFinder {
    public String findProtein(String dna) {
        String fpL = dna.toLowerCase();
        int start = fpL.indexOf("atg");
        int stop = fpL.indexOf("tag", start+3);
        int stop2 = fpL.indexOf("tga", start+3);
        int stop3 = fpL.indexOf("taa", start+3);
        if (start == -1) {
            return "";
        }

        if ((stop - start) % 3 == 0) {
            return fpL.substring(start, stop+3);
        }

        if ((stop2 - start) % 3 == 0) {
            return fpL.substring(start, stop2+3);
        }

        if ((stop3 - start) % 3 == 0) {
            return fpL.substring(start, stop3+3);
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

However, In the following String "ATT**ATG**CCC**TAA**TAG", the code will first find **ATG**CCCTAA**TAG**, even though TAA is the first "stop" sequence in the string and the number of chars between ATG and TAA is 3.

How can I write this program, so that whichever "STOP" sequence appears first in the string and is n3 away from the start sequence is returned.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions will do.

```
    String input = "ACCATGCCCTAGTTT";
    String expected = "ATGCCCTAG";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ATG)(.{3})*?(TAG|TGA|TAA)",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n", m.start(), m.group());
    }
```

In the above the start position is not necessarily a multiple of 3. If the start position must be a multiple of 3, then it would easiest to make groups of 3 letters and a separator.

```
    input = input.replaceAll(".{3}", "$0,");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ATG,)(.{4})*?(TAG|TGA|TAA),",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n", m.start() * 3 / 4, m.group().replace(",", ""));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From

`if ((stop - start) % 3 == 0) {
            return fpL.substring(start, stop+3);
        }`

It first finds TAG and the return statement is called. If you really want to find the first stop point, add some comaprison logic between `stop`, `stop2` and `stop3` to find which is the smallest index. Then do the `% 3` check for each and return from the first one that is ok, or the whole string if there is not a valid case. Also how about using a regular expression for this problem ? Something in the lines of `(ATG)\w{3}(TAG|TGA|TAA)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the minimum of all stop tags, so I'd write something like this:

```
    [...]
    int minStop = MAXINT;

    if ((stop - start) % 3 == 0 && minStop > stop) {
        minStop = stop;
    }

    if ((stop2 - start) % 3 == 0 && minStop > stop2) {
        minStop = stop2;
    }

    if ((stop3 - start) % 3 == 0 && minStop > stop3) {
        minStop = stop3;
    }

    if (minStop < MAXINT) {
        return fpL.substring(start, minStop+3);
    } else {
      [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a list of any search words, then selects the minimum matched index.

```
public String findProtein(String dna) {
    String fpL = dna.toLowerCase();
    int start = fpL.indexOf("atg");

    List<String> searchWords = new ArrayList<>();
    searchWords.add("tag");
    searchWords.add("tga");
    searchWords.add("taa");

    int start = fpL.indexOf("atg");
    try{
        int startIndex = searchWords.stream().mapToInt(word -> fpL.indexOf(word, 3 + start)).filter(idx -> idx >= 0 && 0 == idx % 3)
                .min().getAsInt();

        return dna.substring(start, startIndex + 3);

    } catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code finds "TAG" first is because the way you've written your code:
Your first `if` statement checks for "TAG". If it finds one, it returns the string between "ATG" and "TAG" and terminates.

What you need to do is create a `min` variable and store the value of the found terminator codon in this `min` (after checking it's really min). NOT using `return`in the `if` statements that search for terminator codons. and returning the `min + 3` only after the three `if` statements executed and determined the real minimum distance from "TAG".

Hope it was useful.